# How to open Gmail mail API permission dialog?

Tags: android, gmail-api

I am working on gmail mail API with custom UI.It's working with some of gmail id but with some it's not working.when I search this issue then find that my email-id dosn't have **Gmail Read Email** permission.

My question is that how to open permission dialog in android app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your permissions in Android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.AUTO_SEND" />
```